# Android Permissions System Deny Button hide

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-permissions

I'm trying to integrate the `system` `permits` `android 6.0 onwards`. The goal is to force the user to accept the permissions to use the app. In the `game CSR` Racing make hiding in the System dialog button refuse permission, but I get access to this dialogue and find ways to hide.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: User and marshmallow must be satisfied, if app is for them

Comment: it's quite tough to change system native code , you can do one more thing if user deny any permission then open that dialog again , open app only if user accept all permission .

Comment: So, @Androider What will Ido?

Comment: Could you see the image example?? Why they could change dialog system?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a bug in Android 6.0.1 where deny button sometimes will be enable, sometimes disable.